# Panel not showing object

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Why my panel is not displaying after I click the button?

I am guessing that my frame is not retrieving my panel.
OR have I made an error when adding the object to panel?

```
public class gui{
    JPanel panel= new JPanel();
     
    public gui() {
        JFrame frame= new JFrame("GUI");         
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        addBtns();
        frame.add(button1);
        frame.add(button2);
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.setBounds(350, 100, 500, 750);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(panel);           
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void displayNodes() {   
        DrawingCanvas dc = new DrawingCanvas(100,100,vertex, path);
        panel.add(dc);      
    }
    
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        new gui();
    }
    
    public void addBtns() {    
        button1.setBounds(110,380,180,65);
        userInput.setBounds(245,145,50,35);
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            displayNodes();
            }
        });
    } 
}
```

Comment: @nitind: that won't change a thing, since the `JFrame#add(...)` method delegates directly to `contentPane.add(...)`.

Comment: 1. Better to use a CardLayout when swapping components. 2. If you must do it "by hand", be sure to call `revalidate()` then `repaint()` on the container after adding components to it. 3. Avoid use of null layouts and instead learn and use the layout managers.